# NULL Values in the ID field if I copy features from a shapefile layer to geopackage layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, table

I can't figure out this problem. If I copy from my shapefile layer with copy/paste to another layer which is a geopackage layer, I get NULL values in the ID field. Do you have any ideas?

The added pictures are the layers attribute tables before I pasted.

[[image]]

[[image]

Comment: Your title indicates the issue is an "IF" field, but the body specifies "ID". Please [Edit] the Question for consistency.

Comment: Only one of the two layers in your screenshots has an `id` field, the other one is `fid`. That are two different names and thus different fields.

Comment: and neither of them shows any Nulls -